# enable view depending on other view's attribute - android databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I have a TextInputLayout whose error is enabled and depending on some stuff the error gets disabled. The thing is that I have a button disabled but I want to enable it when the error of the other view disappears. Do you know how it works by using Data Binding? Thanks. My code is this one but is not reacting on error enable/disable changes.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorText"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout.Dense">
            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                style="@style/outlinedTextInputEditText.Multilines"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:text="@={viewModel.name}"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/acceptBtn"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.accept()}"
                android:enabled="@{!name.isErrorEnabled()}"
                style="@style/materialButton.Text"
                android:text="@string/str_accept" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct then you want button to be enabled or disabled based in the text changes if so then do something like below.

create binding adapter for setting text watcher like this.

```
    @BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
    @JvmStatic
    fun addOnTextChangedListener(textView: TextInputEditText, listener: TextWatcher) {
        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(listener)
    }
```

second, pass the listener in the layout like this. `app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.nameWatcher}"`

```
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorText"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout.Dense">
        
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/outlinedTextInputEditText.Multilines"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.nameWatcher}"
            android:text="@={viewModel.name}"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in your view model create text watcher and as soon as the text changes check for text validity and enable and disable the button using some **MutableLiveData** or **ObservableBoolean**

```
val nameWatcher = object :TextWatcher {
  override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    //here change button enable disable using some mutable live data or observable boolean
  }

  override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

}
```